# Embed Eventbrite Event Creator on my website

Tags: eventbrite

I want to use event Brite as the Event creating system for in my Web Application.

Since there is no api to do the same by EventBrite and we cant't embed the complete eventbrite site in an iframe how do we go about it.

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just discussed this on the forum but so that others may see as well, we hope to have full event creation available within the next month. You can, however, update events by POSTing parameters to the Event Details endpoint including event name, event description, etc..

We will also have Event Copy available in the very near future as well.

Answer (score 1):

Event creation is fully available in V3.

You can find all the details for the Event endpoint here http://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/#ebapi-post-events.

Event Object http://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/formats/event/#ebapi-std:format-event